# Android WebView loadUrl and add Script

Tags: javascript, android

How can I add my `Script` to loaded code from URL? I try to use `AsyncTask`, send http request and set code to `WebView`, but then is not loading images and page dosn't work well.

```
        @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        webView.loadData( result, "text/html", "UTF-8" );
    }
```

I doing something wrong ?

Comment: i think `loadDataWithBaseURL` is better when you try to load webview data with Script at runtime ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to run html file runtime then try using this code.

```
 webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", result, "text/html", "UTF-8",null);
```

And make sure if you want to use any css or javascript file then put it into android assest folder..

Comment: ok, but i want to open URL from http, not file. When i do like your answer, must download, css, script, image and other files.